# how do i enable the option to allow comments on certain posts in the JVpress wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, comments

The option seems to have been disabled somewhere and i cant find which file it is in to enable them again. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins for it. There is a post regarding this in [this blog](http://wordpresskillertips.blogspot.com/2011/04/effective-comment-management-in.html). I think the last to plugins in the post serves your need.

The best for always getting a plugin is the wordpress plugins section http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/